# Nokia 7 plus network issues

Tags: mobile-data, mobile-network, nokia

I bought a used Nokia 7 plus not long ago and it worked perfectly at first. 
But recently I have been encountering multiple problems concerning the mobile network connection of my phone. 
 Those include:

- I am unable to get a connection to the network in spots where I get a connection using another phone (so the problem is definitely unrelated to my network service provider)
- If I do get a connection the mobile data doesn't work or is very weak
- Sometimes the phone claims to have a 4g connection to the internet but I can't even to a simple google search

What's weird is that this problem is not consistent, so sometimes I do manage to connect to a network and even to the internet...

Is this a software related problem or is my network card faulty? 
If the latter shouuld be the case, would replacing the network card fix my problem?

Any help regarding my problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: As I said, the problem is unrelated to my network provider as my current SIM card works perfectly on other phones...

Comment: See if the behavior persists in safe mode (Google how to put your device in safe mode). If it behaves normally, it points to some installed app creating trouble

Comment: Network problems like those you have encountered are very unlikely to be caused by the SIM card. More likely is a hardware or software problem of the phone itself.

Comment: @beeshyams thanks for the recommendation; but the problem persists even in safe mode. It has to be hardware related then. Do you think replacing the network card would solve my problems?

Comment: I am not qualified to recommend. It's best you take it to a service center. The first thing they do is ask you to factory reset, so back up your important data. You may as well do that yourself and test to see if it makes a difference //Bottom line - go to qualified folks who can get to the root of problem